# How to mix the custom SQL and dynamic filter sql in JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a custom SQL as below:

```
  select * from 
    (
        select shp.id, shp.status, shp.establish_date, shp.type  
        from shop shp
        inner join book bk 
        on shp.id = bk.shop_id 
        where 
        and shp.id not in 
        (
            select distinct bl.shop_id from banned_list bl 
            where 
            bl.country_risk = 'HIGH'
        )
    ) t1
```

However, I may also want to add dynamic filters of the fields shp.id, shp.status, shp.establish_date, shp.type. Also, there are pagination and sorting.

If I use specification, it will be complicated and difficult to maintain.
If I use the native SQL query, there is a lot of string splitting and joining and hazards to SQL injection.

What is the best solution in JPA?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Querydsl](http://querydsl.com/index.html), it supports dynamic filters, native queries, and so on... Also `spring-data-jpa` has been supported this extension. The coolest thing is builder syntax really easy to read & maintain. Another [Doc](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-querydsl) for you.